# Open resource file from phone file system

Tags: lwuit, codenameone

Is it possible in codename one to download a resource file from server, store it in phone memory, and open in application? It can be a good opportunity to support application after release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. 
You can just download the file using a standard `ConnectionRequest` and save it using the `Storage` API. The `Resources` class has an `open` method that accepts an `InputStream` for you to open this later on.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did as you tell. I start my application, opened standart(minimal .res file). Then I download my full(updated) resource file using addToQueueAndWait, then use Storage.getInstance().writeObject((byte[]) event.getMetaData()). But when I load resource Resources.open(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream(Constants.RESOURCES)); got ugly exception

Comment: java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 10
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:639)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:547)
 at com.sun.lwuit.ui.util.Resources.openFileImpl(Resources.java:196)

Comment: thanks God i fixed the problem using ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: You need to either use writeObject with readObject. Or use createInputStream with createOutputStream. When you write an object additional meta-data is written not just the array.